# Why do we need a second sigma-algebra to define a measurable function?

Tags: measure-theory

I know that a measurable function is defined on two measurable spaces $(\Omega_1, \mathcal F_1)$ and $(\Omega_2, \mathcal F_2)$.

My problem is that I don't understand why we need the second sigma-algebra $\mathcal F_2$.

What's the harm in defining a measurable function as a function which fulfills the condition: for all  $A \subseteq\Omega_2: f^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal F_1$?

I know that we would include non-measurable sets this way but why can't the function map to these kind of sets?
My understanding is that it has to do with the integrability of the function f.

Is that correct?

Comment: Don't you mean $A\subseteq\Omega_2$?

Comment: Yes i do mean that.

Answer (score 1):

If there is freedom in choosing $\mathcal F_2$ then it is possible to give functions $f:\Omega_1\to\Omega_2$ with $f^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal F_1$ for all subsets of $\Omega_2$ the predicate "measurable".

This simply by choosing $\mathcal F_2=\wp(\Omega_2)$.

This happens e.g. if we are observing discrete random variables that only take values in a countable set $\Omega_2$.

Observe however that - if $\mathcal F_2$ is a proper subcollection of $\wp(\Omega_2)$ - this is a **stronger** demand than $f^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal F_1$ for all $A\in\mathcal F_2$.

So lots of functions that might be useful might become unmeasurable if we replace a suitable $\mathcal F_2$ by $\wp(\Omega_2)$.

It is at first hand the more basic "measurability" that suffers under this. The "integrability" that you suggests also suffers, but this merely because integral functions are measurable.

Comment: So in other words we want the input value of the function f to be measurable as well as the output values of f?

Comment: No, we want functions to be measurable. If functions must satisfy $f^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal F_1$ for **all** subsets $A\subseteq\Omega_2$ in order to be measurable then lots of them will not be measurable. We want to avoid that.

Comment: I think thats what I wanted to say. We want the preimage to be part of a sigma-algebra (so it is measurable) and we want the function values to be part of a sigma-algebra (so it is measurable as well). Is that a correct way of saying it?

Comment: What do mean by "function values"? Normally that stands for elements $f(\omega)$ of $\Omega_2$ and not elements of $\Omega_2$ are involved in measurability but *subsets* of $\Omega_2$. Do you mean images like $f(A)$ where $f:\Omega_1\to\Omega_2$ and $A\in\mathcal F_1$ perhaps?

Comment: I mean functions where every $A \in F_1$ and every $f(A) \in F_2$. Is that different from the definition of a measurable function?

Comment: That is indeed different. It is only demanded that $f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal F_1$ for every $B\in\mathcal F_2$. Not that also $f(A)\in\mathcal F_2$ for all $A\in\mathcal F_1$.

Comment: Ok I will try to put it in words again. For a measurable function we are only interested in the images which are measurable (i.e. $f(A) \in F_2)$. Then we take a look at the corresponding preimages and want them to be measurable, too (i.e. preimages $A \in F_1$). There could be other images of f which are not measurable (i.e. $f(A)$ is not an element of $F_2$) but we are not interested in those. Is that correct?

Comment: We are absolutely **not** interested in images. Only in preimages of elements of $\mathcal F_2$. These preimages must be measurable which means that they must belong to $\mathcal F_1$. If e.g. $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is a random variable, then we are interested in the probability that $X\in[0,1]$. Here $[0,1]\in\mathcal F_2$ and $X^{-1}([0,1])\in\mathcal F_1$ hence can be measured. If $P$ denotes the probability measure then we find $P(X\in[0,1])=P(X^{-1}([0,1])$.

Comment: I think this brings me back to my original question. Why are we only interested in the preimages of elements of $F_2$? Why don't we consider all preimages of elements of $\Omega_2$ and see which ones are measurable?

Comment: Your original question was about the *measurability of functions*. If $f$ is a measurable function then indeed it does not harm to look at preimages of sets $A\notin\mathcal F_2$ but you pleaded for *definition of measurability* that would exclude many useful functions.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for your time.